# how to use the groovy maven plugin

Tags: groovy, gmaven

I want to auto compile and run test when I use `mvn test` or `mvn install`

I used to use `gmaven-plugin` and it works will.

But when I use the `groovy-maven-plugin`,the new version of gmaven, it doesn't work!

So how to config?

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- gmaven-plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
        <source/>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-2.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

<!-- groovy-maven-plugin -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What happens when it is not working? do you get an error message?

Comment: I believe the original groovy maven plugin is no longer under development, generally the Eclipse Groovy compiler plugin is favored for maven: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven

Comment: @drorb there is no errors,but when I run `mvn test`,the new plugin will not run the groovy test. But the version `1.5` will.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the Groovy Eclipse Compiler, there's also a new [GMavenPlus plugin](http://groovy.github.io/GMavenPlus/index.html) that can support joint compilation.

In regards to testing, here's a POM sample of my project which has the GMavenPlus plugin working with Spock.

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>5</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the GMaven 2.x [documentation](http://groovy.github.io/gmaven/index.html) it no longer supports any integration for compilation of Groovy sources. As an alternative it is suggested to use the [Groovy Eclipse Compiler](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven).
The [groovy-maven-plugin](http://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/index.html) goals allows to open a groovy console or execute a groovy script, but no longer have the compilation goals.